# Trouble with variable assignment and scope while updating my data source in Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, flask, scope, bokeh

I'm trying to use callbacks to update the data source in a bokeh graph running off of bokeh server embedded in a Flask app. I'm getting an error when I try to change the period via the 'period' select widget. My error is

```
ERROR:bokeh.server.protocol_handler:error handling message
 message: Message 'PATCH-DOC' content: {'events': [{'kind': 'ModelChanged', 'model': {'id': '1166'}, 
'attr': 'value', 'new': '2y'}], 'references': []}
 error: UnboundLocalError("local variable 'current_feature' referenced before assignment")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\protocol_handler.py", line 90, in handle
    work = await handler(message, connection)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\session.py", line 67, in _needs_document_lock_wrapper
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\session.py", line 261, in _handle_patch
    message.apply_to_document(self.document, self)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\protocol\messages\patch_doc.py", line 100, in apply_to_document
    doc._with_self_as_curdoc(lambda: doc.apply_json_patch(self.content, setter))
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1150, in _with_self_as_curdoc
    return f()
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\protocol\messages\patch_doc.py", line 100, in <lambda>
    doc._with_self_as_curdoc(lambda: doc.apply_json_patch(self.content, setter))
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 411, in apply_json_patch
    patched_obj.set_from_json(attr, value, models=references, setter=setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py", line 341, in set_from_json
    descriptor.set_from_json(self, json, models, setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\descriptors.py", line 612, in set_from_json
    models, setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\descriptors.py", line 321, in set_from_json
    self._internal_set(obj, json, setter=setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\descriptors.py", line 763, in _internal_set
    self._real_set(obj, old, value, hint=hint, setter=setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\descriptors.py", line 832, in _real_set
    self._trigger(obj, old, value, hint=hint, setter=setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\descriptors.py", line 909, in _trigger
    obj.trigger(self.name, old, value, hint, setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\model.py", line 661, in trigger
    super().trigger(attr, old, new, hint=hint, setter=setter)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\util\callback_manager.py", line 157, in trigger
    self._document._notify_change(self, attr, old, new, hint, setter, invoke)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1042, in _notify_change
    self._trigger_on_change(event)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1132, in _trigger_on_change
    self._with_self_as_curdoc(event.callback_invoker)
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py", line 1150, in _with_self_as_curdoc
    return f()
  File "c:\users\grego\onedrive\projects\python projects\ey\eyflask_virtualenv\eyvenv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\util\callback_manager.py", line 155, in invoke
    callback(attr, old, new)
  File "C:\Users\grego\Documents\GitHub\EY-DashboardV2\EYvenv\app\routes.py", line 120, in update_plot
    'y' : new_data[current_feature]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_feature' referenced before assignment
```

It seems to be something with variable scopes. I just can't see how I am possibly referencing the 'current_feature' variable before I am initializing it? Any help is appreciated.

Code in question:

```
def create_stocks_graph(doc):
    feature_names = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
    periods = ['1d','5d','1mo','3mo','6mo','1y','2y','5y','10y','ytd','max']
    default_period = 'ytd'
    default_feature = 'Close'
    current_feature = default_feature # keep this
    data = companyObject.getHistoricalPricesDf(period=default_period)
    source = ColumnDataSource(data={

    'x' : data.index,

    'y' : data['Close']
    })

    p = figure(title=f"Stocks at {default_feature} for past {default_period}", 
    x_axis_label='Date', 
    y_axis_label=default_feature,
    tools="pan,wheel_zoom,reset",
    plot_width=600,
    plot_height=600,
    x_axis_type="datetime") 

    # x ticks
    data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
    data.index.name = 'Date'
    data.sort_index(inplace=True)
    x_ticks = [d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y)")[:-1] for d in data.index.date]

    # make graph
    p.line('x', 'y', legend_label="Stock Price", line_width=2, source=source)

    def update_plot(attr, old, new):
        if new in feature_names:
            print('updating feature')
            print('old:', old)
            print('new:', new)
            current_feature = new
            source.data['y'] = data[new]
        else:
            # get new data and update x ticks
            print('updating period')
            print('old:', old)
            print('new:', new)
            new_data = companyObject.getHistoricalPricesDf(period=new)
            new_data.index = pd.to_datetime(new_data.index)
            new_data.index.name = 'Date'
            new_data.sort_index(inplace=True)
            x_ticks = [d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y)")[:-1] for d in new_data.index.date]
            source.data = {
                'x' : new_data.index,
                'y' : new_data[current_feature]
            }


    # add selects
    period_select = Select(title="Period", value=default_period, options=periods)
    feature_select = Select(title="Feature", value=default_feature, options=feature_names)
    period_select.on_change("value", update_plot) # update period
    feature_select.on_change("value", update_plot) # update feature

    doc.add_root(layout(
        [feature_select, period_select], 
        [p]))
```

Comment: Is the update_plot function supposed to be inside the create_stocks_graph function?

Comment: yes because the select widgets need to be able to call it. It's the callback function.

Comment: Inside your update_plot function, within the else statement, write after the line "x_ticks =". Add a print(current_feature) and print(len(current_feature)) and print(type(current_feature)). What output do you get?